# Question about Ebbinghaus's Mathematical Logic: p.21

Tags: logic

Let $S_{gr}$ be the symbol set $\{\circ,e\}$ for group theory.
The example 4.1 is

> (a) For all symbol set $S$, the empty string $\Box$ is neither an $S$-term nor $S$-formula.
>
> (b1) $\circ$ is not an $S_{gr}$-term.
>
> (b2) $\circ\circ v_1$ is not an $S_{gr}$-term.

In the proof of (b2), to show that every $S_{gr}$-term is distinct from $\circ\circ v_1$, the proof of induction have to show that $\circ t_1t_2$ is distinct from $\circ\circ v_1$. Thus it says

> If  $\circ t_1t_2=\circ\circ v_1$, by (a), we would have $t_1=\circ$ and $t_2=v_1$. But $t_1=\circ$ contradicts (b1).

But how could I derive $t_1=\circ$ and $t_2=v_1$ by (a)?

( [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2UHb.jpg) is the original text, 2nd edition. )

Comment: Terms are finite sequences of "basic" symbols: $\circ, e$ and variables.

Comment: If $\circ t_1 t_2 = \circ \circ v_1$ we have to "match" the basic symbols of the two sequences. For the first one, we have $\circ$ in both cases: Ok. For the second one, we have $\circ$ in the second sdquence. But we know, by (a), that the empty string is not a term: thus, $t_2$ cannot be the emtys tring, and so we are forced to match $\circ$ with $t_1$ and $v_2$ with $t_2$.

Comment: Ah ! Thanks a lot！